# How to choose between data-driven pattern or intuition?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-strategies, confounding

I am performing a multivariate logistic regression (This could very well be any other kind of regression method) to study the effect of some predictor variables on the probability of event. I have some prior knowledge that informs me that the effect of a continuous predictor variable $X_1$ should be monotonic. However, when I use a natural cubic spline to expand $X_1$ and include it together with the other variables, I got a $V$-shaped effect for $X_1$.

For example, if the event is death from poisoning, $X_1$ is the exposure of subject to certain hazardous material.

I could find no reasonable explanation of the downward sloping part of the effect. What would you suggest I do? Here are some potential solutions I have considered, neither is very satisfactory:

1. ignore the downward sloping part, and just fit a simple spline for the upward sloping part
2. trust the result from the natural cubic spline and then apply the model directly

My feeling is that the best approach is probably to uncover the root of the strange phenomenon, likely a confounding variable. But I am not sure how to even start on this? Any suggestion would be appreciated!
[image]

Comment: I don't think you'll get help from generic stats forum. You clearly have domain issues here.

Comment: Can this unusual slope be produced by several outliers? In other words, can you exclude small amount of data points and get intuitive curve?

Comment: @Aksakal: Thanks for your comment. I felt this question is general enough that researchers from different domains might have run into it.

Comment: @GermanDemidov: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked that the distribution of data - about 50% of them are below the "trough" of the curve, so not very likely due to a few outliers.

Comment: As for me, I would never ignore the data. I guess you did not make any error in fitting (you can see an effect by eye), so you should work on the explanation of the effect. Could you provide a plot of your data here? The best solution I would recommend is to repeat measures (make a replicate cohort) and check possible measurements' effect (sometimes your method of measurement can make such tricks). Try to do PCA if it is suitable, for more information you can google "batch effect correction".

Comment: @GermanDemidov: plot attached. When you say repeat measures - do you mean trying to rule out the peculiarity of the specific sample I am taking?

Comment: I guess here you do not need to repeat the measures. You see an effect here, it can not be ignored. Your plot is symmetric. Could you accidentally miss one of the signs (+/-)? Should not you use absolute value of your data points? Also, could you elaborate on x/y axis more?

Comment: @GermanDemidov: The positive and negative signs are important here, so I would prefer not to use absolute value. X-axis is my predictor variable which has been divided into 30 equal bins (from low to high value of X), Y-axis is a plot of the parameter estimate for the indicator variable which indicates which bin the observation is in. I found that by adding Age into the model, the left (inexplicable) part becomes significantly lower, while the right part becomes 'taller'. So it is probably just some variables that I did not know to include... I will leave it at this.Thx for your input!